# Lookup tables in Spring Boot JPA Hibernate CRUD repositories

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use Spring Boot with JPA autoconfigured CRUD repositories, Hibernate, and MySQL. I'm having some trouble getting lookup tabled working the way I'd expect.

The `User` entity has a property called `status` which is currently either `enabled` or `disabled`. However, I cannot hard code these values, because they must be changeable without a recompile. So I figure a lookup table contains the possible values of `status`, represented as a many-to-one relationship on the `User` model. The `status` table can have a foreign key column that references the auto-generated primary key of the status in question. I feel like this is fairly standard stuff in non-ORM SQL coding. Here is my attempt to do this with JPA:

the user model class, User.java:

```
package com.example.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String guid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "status", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Status status;

    private String description;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(final String guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("User[id='%d', guid='%s', description='%s']", id, guid, description);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof User)) { return false; }
        final User rhs = (User) obj;
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(guid, rhs.getGuid()).build();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder().append(guid).build();
    }

    ...getters and setters...

}
```

and nested model Status.java:

```
package com.example.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Status {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Status() {
    }

    public Status(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Status[id='%d', name='%s', description='%s']", id, name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Status)) { return false; }
        final Status rhs = (Status) obj;
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(name, rhs.getName()).build();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder().append(name).build();
    }

    ...getters and setters...

}
```

and UserRepository.java

```
package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.example.model.User;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    boolean existsByGuid(String guid);

    User findByGuid(String guid);

    boolean deleteByGuid(String guid);

}
```

And here's the SQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `status_id` (`status`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`status`) REFERENCES `status` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have inserted some test rows into the database to check the read function of the CRUD repository. I can see that the lookup table is being referenced properly.

```
INSERT INTO `status` (`name`) VALUES
    ('enabled'),
    ('disabled');

INSERT INTO `user` (`guid`, `status`) 
    SELECT 'rick', `status`.`id` FROM `status` WHERE `status`.`name` = 'enabled';

INSERT INTO `user` (`guid`, `status`) 
    (SELECT 'morty', `status`.`id` FROM `status` WHERE `status`.`name` = 'disabled');
```

Here's the JSON stringified output:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "guid": "rick",
            "status": {
                "name": "enabled"
            },
            "description": null
        },
        {
            "guid": "morty",
            "status": {
                "name": "disabled"
            },
            "description": null
        }
    ],
}
```

The problem comes when we want to POST JSON to create a new user. I can use a JSON body like the following:

```
{
  "guid": "jerry",
  "status": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "disabled"
  }
}
```

This works, but it has a flaw. It is specifically passing the ID of the status. This value is internal to our system. We don't want our API users to have to keep track of this key, and our system does not output it. It really kinda defeats the purpose of the lookup table, imho. I would prefer to let the user simply pass:

```
{
  "guid": "jerry",
  "status": {
    "name": "disabled"
  }
}
```

I would be even more happy if they could just pass `"status":"disable"`, instead, and have that automatically resolve into the lookup table.

```
{
  "guid": "jerry",
  "status": "disabled"
}
```

However, with my current configurations, JPA does not understand that it should use an existing row in the lookup table with the name `disabled`, when the primary key is not explicitly passed.

```
2017-11-26 22:21:57.174  WARN 3748 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.a.i.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions    : HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
    Unsaved transient entity: ([com.example.model.Status#<null>])
    Dependent entities: ([[com.example.model.User#<null>]])
    Non-nullable association(s): ([com.example.model.User.status])
2017-11-26 22:21:57.213 ERROR 3748 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.example.model.User.status -> com.example.model.Status; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.example.model.User.status -> com.example.model.Status] with root cause

org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.example.model.User.status -> com.example.model.Status
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(ActionQueue.java:414) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(SessionImpl.java:619) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:777) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

As a workaround, I can create a StatusRepository (which extends CrudRepository) and do an explicit lookup, but this would be slower and less elegant than doing this all in one repository call.

Please, what is the annotation(s), and/or whatever other change(s), that will let me create a new user without multiple repository calls, and without the user having to explicitly pass the ID?

Please note, I've omitted some classes to save space, but the [entire example project](https://github.com/helo478/spring-boot-data-jpa-sandbox/releases/tag/11_26_2017) can be found on GitHub.

Comment: If you can make the `Status.name` column ID then it would be possible.

Comment: @11thdimension, that is good to hear. Can you point me toward an example of how this would work?

Comment: If `name` column in `Status` class is unique then you can mark this with `@Id` and remove the `Long id` field. That way when you send the `{"name":"disabled"}` JPA would be able to fetch it itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are going to have to do the lookup since the key isn't being provided.

But you can counteract the performance concerns you have by using a L2 cache configuration.  Given that your `Status` entities rarely change, they're an ideal candidate for L2 cache storage. This prevents the network and database lookup costs.

Comment: Is there some more JPA appropriate way to achieve the same thing that I'm trying to do with my lookup table? It seems very strange that JPA wouldn't have an easy way to do this.

Comment: Not sure what "strange" means. If you want to associate an entity with another you have to have an identifier. When creating a User and only passing the name (which is not the PK) of Status you unfortunately have to lookup Status via name, get the entity and associate it with the User before creation. If you want to hide Status PK from the user in the front-end for security purpose you can use indirect object reference.

Comment: L2 cache is a cache by Id. Your lookup findByName will lookup the ID by name, so it won't hit L2 cache..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are couple of options.

1. Use spring data jpa [getOne](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-) method. Or it's [counterpart](https://vladmihalcea.com/entitymanager-find-getreference-jpa/) in hibernate:
2. Use "String name" as @Id or @NaturalId.
3. Hibernate supports persistence of child entity even if it is a brand new entity but with id, i.e.
   `user.setStatus(new Status(1, "disabled"))`. So, you can cache the values yourself. And lookup them in your own cache.